# Rails 5 - How to Have Controllers inside Subfolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a subfolder `api` in my controllers folder.
So when I call `POST "/api/auth"` I would like the program to get there using rails conventions.
I.E. **I don't want to write the route for each call**, but to use rails "patent" that makes rails go to CRUD actions understanding the PUT, POST, GET by itself.

So in my `routes.rb` I have:

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :debts, :auth
  end
```

But when I POST (or GET) with `localhost:3000/api/auth` I get:

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::AuthController)`

What am I missing?

Please note that I also need to have many controllers inside the subfolder. Is there a short `match` for all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your controller in a sub folder too en then do e.g.

```
# /app/controllers/api/debts_controller.rb
module Api
  class DebtsController < ApiController
  end
end

# /app/controllers/api/auth_controller.rb
module Api
  class AuthController < ApiController
  end
end
```

Then in base controller folder:

```
# /app/controllers/api_controller.rb
class ApiController < ApplicationController
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to namespace the class also in order to get this working.

The following 2 ways can be used:

```rb
module Api
  class AuthController < ApplicationController
    # Your controller code here
  end
end

class Api::AuthController < ApplicationController
  # Your controller code here
end
```

If you have some code that needs to be run for every controller inside the Api namespace, you can make an Api base controller, but it's not necessary.

Comment: It works, but only if in routes.rb I put the lines of "namespace" above all lines. When there was another routing line before the namespace, like: " root 'login#login' ", it didn't work. WHY?